# Indirect inguinal and gym? Can it be done?

Tags: weightlifting, hernia

So I was informed by the doctor today by checking the ultrasound results that I got Indirect Inguinal hernia. He also informed me that it is a really small one and I do not need to make an operation. And finally he told me not to lift heavy weight..

So what will happen if I continue lifting weights in the gym? Is it gonna make it more painful? Is there specific exercises to avoid or to focus more that could help? Dont want to stop gym :/

Anyone that has similar problem and didn't not went for operation?

Comment: We don't support medical advise questions. You have an opinion from a MD, if you question it, seek a different MD. All you will get are "well, my experience is" type answers which may or may not be relevant to you specifically.

Answer (score 4):

> So what will happen if I continue lifting weights in the gym?

Training with a hernia is usually no big deal. I did it for 5-6 years before I decided to get mine fixed. But a hernia CAN rupture if you do particular things wrong, and if this hapens, it will be extremely painful, and you will require immediate surgery.

> Is it gonna make it more painful?

Not necessarily painful, but annoying. Very annoying.

> Is there specific exercises to avoid or to focus more that could help? Dont want to stop gym :/

There are lots of exercises that can irritate or damage a hernia. I'm not going to list them, because it would be impossible to list them all. Besides, my best advice is you get your hernia repaired sooner rather than later.

it just so happens I've had a hernia repair. I got it done electively. In my case, it was small, and the doctor said "you don't *need* surgery, so it's up to you", but I elected to have it done anyway, because while it didn't hurt, I was sick of feeling it there when lifting weights.

If you intend to keep training with weights, I highly suggest you get your hernia repaired. It's a very small and non-invasive surgery, with a short recovery time. A couple days of at-home rest, followed by a couple weeks of no training, followed by 4-6 weeks of light training, followed by being as good as new. And at this point, you can train however heavy you want.

The type of repair will be very dependent on the size of your hernia. For most cases, a small mesh is implanted behind the hernia. In other cases, it's so small it can just be sewed shut.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! doctor said i had a really small(4.5mm i think) but i feel the pain sometimes. Do you have any link/resources that I can check what exercises to do or not or who specializes in this kind of info (I don't think gym trainers can answer these questions).

Comment: No, sorry, I don't have a link for this. Against my better judgement, I wrote an answer that was pure opinion (which is not really suited for this site). The recommendations I give are based on experience, and second-hand wisdom from my own doctor. But I felt it was worth sharing, so even though it might get deleted, I feel it was worth writing. And I agree; gym trainers wouldn't want to train you knowing you have a hernia. At least they shouldn't. They'd tell you to see a doctor, and this is my recommendation as well.